# Validate if form data is a present select input option

Tags: php

I have a select input:

```
<label for="gender">Gender:</label>
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

How to validate whether submitted data belongs to select input?

I have tried:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['gender'] !== 'Male' || $_POST['gender'] !== 'Female') {
      // perform redirect
}
```

Comment: Wrong operator. Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: You would have to use `&&`, as Jon said, since the you want to check that it is not equal to Male, *and* not equal to Female, in which case it is invalid.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I just want to validate that the value is either Male or Female as it should be.

Comment: Try looking at `$_POST` array by `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner way to do it would be

```
$options = array( 'Male', 'Female' ); 

if( !in_array( $_POST['gender'], $options  ) )  // if Male or Female are not in $_POST 
    // redirect
```

Comment: Spiffy way of doing that. +1 from me for that.

Comment: Nice, although you should change the $options and $_POST['gender'] around, the array has to be at the end, thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['gender'] != 'Male' && $_POST['gender'] != 'Female') {
      // perform redirect
}
```

The above will redirect if neither option is checked. But personally, I prefer to do a '--Choose--' option, and simply check against it.

```
<label for="gender">Gender:</label><select id="gender" name="gender">
<option value="0" selected=selected>--Choose--</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>

if ($_POST['gender'] != '0') {
      // perform redirect
}
```

Also, your original will work with:

```
if ($_POST['gender'] == 'Male' || $_POST['gender'] == 'Female') {
      // perform redirect
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't validate if the value is either Male or Female though.

Comment: While technically correct, this will work on any select. The '0' is auto-selected. So, as long as 0 isn't sent, then another option has been chosen. I would hate to hard-code all the 'options' of every select, this simplifies that and can work on any select you put the '0' in.  Granted, it would also allow an injection of a false choice. But this is also why I would send integers, and not hard coded names.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
    extract( $_POST );

    if ( !isset($Male) && !isset($Female) ) {
    // redirect
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid passing literal values altogether when these are in a known range/domain.

The form can be generated using an indexed value, e.g.

```
<?php
$options = [];
$options['gender'] = [1 => 'Male', 2 => 'Female'];
?>
<label for="gender">Gender:</label>
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <?php foreach ($options['gender'] as $i => $name):?>
    <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$name?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Then your input validation logic would simply check for value presence in the `$options` array, e.g.

```
<?php
if (isset($options['gender'][$_POST['gender']])) {
    // 
}
```

Furthermore, consider using existing form generation tools (e.g. https://github.com/gajus/dora) and input validation libraries (https://github.com/gajus/vlad). I am the author of both libraries, and each library will refer you to the existing alternatives. The purpose of using an existing library for generating form and handling input validation is to avoid re-inventing the wheel and protecting yourself from silly security bugs that are often overlooked when handling forms, e.g. XSS.